# Insert into a map

Tags: c++

I hope that someone could help me. So I know that in `std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<int, int>> output;`. I can insert like this : `output[key] = {value, value1};`, but can I use the insert method to do this ? Could someone please help me ?

Comment: or this - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert

Comment: Sorry, I can't find similar example ?

Comment: What exactly have you tried and what does not work? `insert` expects `value_type`, which is `std::pair<const int, std::pair<int, int>>` in your case, as you may find out in [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map).

Comment: Well, I've tried this : output.insert(2, {2,2});, but it's not really working. I think I'm using C++ 17

Comment: `output.insert({1,{2,3}});`. [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/XnAMHZ)

Comment: So, it's basically pair with 1 value in pair with two ?

Comment: Thank you for the help !

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

> `output.insert(pair<int, pair<int, int>>(1,pair<int, int>(3,4)));`

See this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/

Comment: I'd suggest https://cppreference.com/ as a *much* better reference site to point people at. It is much more complete than cplusplus.com and has much fewer errors and mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Or simply:

```
#include <unordered_map>

int main()
{
   std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<int, int>> output;

   output[5] = { 10, 15 }; // your way
   output.insert({ 10, {20,30} }); // using brace intializer
   output.insert(std::make_pair(15, std::make_pair(30, 45))); // using make_pair
}
```